# Eliminar bloqueo de fondo de modal en Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

He buscado bastante e incluso en la documentación oficial pero no he encontrado solución o tal vez lo interpreto mal, juzgue por favor:

Intento eliminar el bloque de fondo de un modal, o sea, necesito que este sea capaz de interactuar con su fondo y además, al hacer click este modal se actualice(en el fondo, solo necesito el espacio de trabajo) ya que tengo una tabla construida y al hacer click necesito que esta descripción aparezca a un costado, les dejaré un fiddle con el ejemplo:

```css
.modal.left .modal-dialog {
 position: fixed;
 margin: auto;
 width: 320px;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left .modal-content {
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal.left .modal-body {
 padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}

.modal.left.fade .modal-dialog {
 left: -320px;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.left.fade.show .modal-dialog {
 left: 0;
}

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
.modal-content {
 border-radius: 0;
 border: none;
}

.modal-header {
 border-bottom-color: #eeeeee;
 background-color: #fafafa;
}

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
 background-color: #78909c;
}

.demo {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.btn-demo {
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container demo">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Left Sidebar Modal
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal left fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="nav flex-sm-column flex-row">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

La idea finalmente, es quitar el backdrop(ya lo hice) y quitar la cssclass del body modal-open(ya lo hice) pero aun así no consigo volver a hacer click en el fondo y se me bloquean los botones, las tablas y los select.

Gracias por su tiempo.

**EDIT** Añado link a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Algorithm-HR/pen/xxKpQON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo debes sobreescribir la clase `modal` con los valores correctos para `height`, `left` y `right`. Te dejo a continuación el código editado.

**RESPUESTA CORTA**

agrega una clase que pise estos valores.

```
.modal {
  height: unset !important;
  right: unset !important;
  bottom: unset !important;
}
```

```css
.modal.left .modal-dialog {
 position: fixed;
 margin: auto;
 width: 320px;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left .modal-content {
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal.left .modal-body {
 padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}

.modal.left.fade .modal-dialog {
 left: -320px;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.left.fade.show .modal-dialog {
 left: 0;
}

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
.modal-content {
 border-radius: 0;
 border: none;
}

.modal-header {
 border-bottom-color: #eeeeee;
 background-color: #fafafa;
}

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
 background-color: #78909c;
}

.demo {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.btn-demo {
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
 outline: 0;
}

.modal {
  height: unset !important;
  right: unset !important;
    bottom: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container demo">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Left Sidebar Modal
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal left fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="nav flex-sm-column flex-row">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: Estimado, a tu respuesta solo le tuve que agregar esto y funcionó: 
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Perfecto ! que bueno que te haya funcionado con lo que le agregaste también.

Comment: Si, lo que agregue habilita el scroll de la pantalla de fondo

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap tiene una clase de nombre `.modal` con las siguientes reglas:

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Las reglas position y width hacen que ocupe todo el contenido de la ventana. Lo que puedes hacer es sobreescribir `width` dándole un ancho fijo(por ejemplo el mismo ancho que tiene tu sidebar: 320px).

En tu propia hoja de estilos puedes sobreescribir esta regla de la siguiente manera:

```
.modal {
    width: 320px !important;
}
```

Comment: Amigo, probé tu respuesta y no funcionó, tengo otros modales además así que afectó el funcionamiento de todo, le puse una clase modal aparte para su descripción y no di con un buen funcionamiento. Entiendo perfecto que la clase modal lo controla, pero se podría realizar solo para 1 modal?